# Using scalamock: Could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type error

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, mocking, scalamock

I am writing unit tests for my spark/scala application. I am using scalamock as well to mock objects, specifically Session / Session Factory.

In one of my test classes, I try to mock the Session. Ex:

```
val mockedSession = mock[Session]
```

However, I get this error:

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type
org.scalamock.util.Defaultable[org.hibernate.SimpleNaturalldLoadAccess]
```

I am getting similar errors no matter the object I mock. The format looks correct.

Comment: what Scala version? What ScalaMock version? What library is this `Session` type from?

Answer (score 0):

From the section "Advanced Topics / Raw Types" in the [documentation](https://scalamock.org/user-guide/advanced_topics/):

```scala
"mocking a java method with raw type" should "work" in {
  implicit val d = new Defaultable[java.util.Enumeration[_]] {
    override val default = null
  }
  implicit val d2 = new Defaultable[java.util.Map[_, _]] {
    override val default = null
  }
  
  val mockedRaw = mock[RawTypeInterface]
}
```

In my case simply importing the offending type resolved the error.